# I don't understand why my code for binary search displays a segmentation error

Tags: c++

I have tested the code for the vector a = {1,5,8,12,13} and x = 23, it sent me a segmentation error, and I don't understand why :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>

using std::vector;

int binary_search(const vector<int> &a, int x) {
    int left = 0, right = (int)a.size(); 
    if(left>right) return -1;
    right = floor((double)(left + right)/2);
    if(a[right] == x){
        return right;
    }
    else if(a[right]>x){
        vector<int> w(a.begin(), a.begin() + right);
        return binary_search(w,x);
    }
    else{
        vector<int> w(a.begin() + right, a.end());
        return binary_search(w,x);
    }
}
```

It should enter to an infinite loop when the vector w created by the program has size 1, no ?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound

Comment: Look at `if(a[right] == x)`. You try to get `a[a.size()]` when the vector is empty or consists of one element. Don't you see a problem here?

Comment: Compile with address sanitizer and you'll likely get a detailed error message. Note that an infinite loop can still easily cause a segault from recursion taking stack space.

Comment: In debug mode use `-fsanitize=leak,address,undefined"`

Comment: `if(left>right) return -1;` is redundant. 0 > something unsigned never happens.

Comment: Instead of copying the vector a bunch, why not just pass it by `ref` with a `start` and `end` index.  Even better, use a `std::span`

Comment: Also when you are creating a new array you will return the position of x in that new array (which is a subarray of a). This won't be the actual answer for the problem for example if the number is in the right part you will give the index of the element in the right half but actual you need (mid + indexInRightPart)

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/binary_search

Comment: @DeepakPatankar And how I put this kind of variable when I use a recursive function ?

Comment: Thank you for sharing the STL algorithm, it is good for my knowledge, but now the goal for me is to implement this algorithm

Comment: @user1032677 I don't understand, pass by ref what ? The vector v with a particular begin and end iterator ?

Comment: @BalPota Instead of passing a truncated array, you can pass the full array and the indexes start and end where you want to do the binary search

Comment: Pass by Ref : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/passing-by-pointer-vs-passing-by-reference-in-c/

Comment: Pass by reference the complete array, if do do pass by value then array will be copied in that function. So to avoid this copying overhead you can pass by reference.

Comment: To avoid infinite loop you shoule use `right -1` and `right + 1`, while creating the two subarrays. Also I would suggest to use a mid variable instead of overwriting right

Comment: I have given a lot of information, hope I am not confusing you.

Comment: Sorry I left for a trip. @DeepakPatankar Thank you for your help, everything seem clear to me, except I don't know how we could start in the part of the vector we want without creating another vector. And we don't need to write right-1 and right+1 because the constructor of the class vector include the first iterator and exclude the last one

Comment: Didn't knew about the `right+1` and `right-1` logic, thanks for sharing it.

Comment: @JesperJuhl [binary_search](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/binary_search) tells you if it is found, [lower_bound](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound) "Returns an iterator pointing to the first element in the range [first, last) that is not less than (i.e. greater or equal to) value, or last if no such element is found."  That being said, `binary_search` is implemented using `lower_bound`.  `lower_bound` is closer to what OP asked for (he is returning an index).

Comment: The pleasure is all mine! Then I wanted to say that we don't have to put right-1, but the right+1 we have to put it (since the constructor includes the first iterator). Thanks to you especially! @DeepakPatankar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can have indexes `start` and `end` which can point to the subarray where you want to do the binary search, this way we don't have to explicitly create a subarray.

```
int binary_search(vector<int> &a, int start, int end, int x) {
    if(start > end) 
       return -1;
    int mid = floor((double)(start + end)/2);
    if(a[mid] == x){
        return mid;
    }
    else if(a[mid] > x){
        return binary_search(a, 0, mid - 1, x);
    }
    else{
        return binary_search(a, mid + 1, end, x);
    }
}
```